# how to redirect to previous page in php with a feedback text

Tags: php, mysql

there is a link **'add class'** ,
when a user clicks it is directed to the page where there is a form where he can add class
and the form action is **$_server['php_self']**
i want when he added class successully to be taken to the previous page(**add_student_stream.php?id=stud_02**)
i tried this but it  does not work and some say it may not work on secured pages

```
$q=mysql_query("insert into student_stream(id,student_id,stream) values('','$id','$stream')");
if($q){
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
}
```

so how can i do this?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION` to track `PHP_SELF` on each page, and so you could assume that the current `PHP_SELF` is the last page you were on.

**Page 1.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['currPage'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST URI'];

if(isset($_GET['error'])){
$errorMessage = htmlspecialchars($_GET['error']);
echo "An error occured. The message was: " . $errorMessage;
}

// The user ends up going to page 2...
```

**Page2.php**

```
session_start();

// the user does something and now you need to redirect them...

$errorMessage = "You made an error.";
header("Location: " . $_SESSION['currPage'] . "?error=" . $errorMessage);
exit;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're setting `theurl` on the previous page before getting to the second page?

Comment: sory i don get u, can u show how do i set theurl??? coz i just placed these codes on a second page

Comment: @internally1 I built you an update to show you more clearly what's going on.

Comment: it take me back , but not to the same url, i want to get back to **student_profile.php?id=stud_01** but it takes me to **student_profile.php**

Comment: it gives this **Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST URl in C:\wam**

Comment: @internally1 it's REQUEST_URI - I miseed the `_` symbol between the words